# Insert into one column data from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

```
Table A
Col1 Col2
101  102
101  103
102  104
104  105

Table B
Col1
101
102
103
104
105
```

I want to take data from Table A and insert it into Table B as a Distinct value in one query
so `INSERT INTO TableB (Col1) (SELECT ...)`

Any ideas?

Comment: A union might work (not in front a SqlServer right now).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
 INSERT INTO TableB (Col1)
 (SELECT Col1 FROM TableA
  UNION
 SELECT Col2 FROM TableA)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT TABLEB (Col1)
SELECT Col1 FROM TABLEA
UNION SELECT COL2 FROM TABLEA
```

For non-distinct, `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use two queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO `TableB` (`Col1`)
SELECT `Col1` FROM `TableA`

INSERT IGNORE INTO `TableB` (`Col1`)
SELECT `Col2` FROM `TableA`
```

Answer (score 0):

insert B (col1) SELECT distinct col1 from A union select distinct col2 from A;